# If $y>\frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}$ is $|x|>\frac{1}{y^\frac{1}{\alpha}}$?

Tags: inequality

If 
$$0<\alpha\leq 1$$
and
$$x,y\in R, y > 0$$
Is it always true that if $y>\frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}$ then $|x|>\frac{1}{y^\frac{1}{\alpha}}$?

Comment: Yes if $x\neq 0$. Also, the assumption $y>0$ is redundant since $1/|x|^\alpha$ is always positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. In fact, because $|x|^{\alpha}, x\neq0$ is always positive and so $y>0$, you can multply and then divide, obtaining:$$|x|^{\alpha}>\frac{1}{y}$$
Taking the $\alpha-$root, we have: $$|x|>\frac{1}{y^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}$$

Comment: Square root?${}$

Comment: @TonyK: sorry, my error. Corrected.